# How to Pass a percentage Variable in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, variables, percentage

I wrote a query in Oracle in which I receive a value from a known table and a known column. Value is the lowest value out of the column's top 2.5%.
The Query below works But the issue is passing the value in a declared variable and I keep Getting a Keyword Missing Error :

```
SELECT PERCENTILE_CONT(0.025) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY known_column DESC) 
FROM known_table
```

ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"

Comment: What do you mean by "passing the value in a declared variable"? What is a declared variable, and how are you attempting to pass the value? If your query works as written, then "percentage" has nothing to do with it; the question would be the same for "passing the value" returned by any query to a "declared variable", whatever that means. For example, how do you "pass the value" returned by `select 1 from dual` to a "declared variable"?

Comment: Can you post complete code showing how you are declaring and using the variable in SQL, the SQL posted is not related to error?

Comment: mathguy, I meant by using the value the query above returns into a variable i previously declared.
I will now show an exemplary code I have attempted.

`DECLARE
deaclared_var NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT PERCENTILE_CONT(0.025) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY known_column DESC) into declared_var FROM known_table;
END;`